# Delete X rows from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to delete X rows from a table having an equal column values. For a better way of this question, I'm writing this question in a sql query way, please understand:

```
DELETE id FROM table_name WHERE column_value = 1 AND user_id = 2;
```

And this query should delete 3 rows. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried for() loop?

Comment: Why do you want to run that query 3 times, won't it be done after the first time?

Comment: You want to remove three rows? Why not use `WHERE column_value IN (...)`? Or do you want to reuse the query on some other tables?

Comment: I want to remove each row after validating that if the limit number is not more then the column_value. If it is then the query should stop

Comment: @AmalMurali: One query will delete all the rows where the `WHERE` clause succeeds. So running it a second time will have no effect.

Comment: Why -1? I've tried my best to simplify the question. Please understand, englsih is not my native language. If the question is unclear please ask more details.

@peterm: I want to delete rows X times where the column_value is exactly equal to 1 in each row

Comment: @user2854563: I've tested my query on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13ccb7/1/0, it succeeded.

Comment: OK, can it delete the rows 3 times (like I asked in the question)? I'm asking this because you've one row in the fiddle and the quesry is deleting only that row.

Comment: Why you're asking "why"? Sorry about this but I'm asking the rows to be deleted X times because I'm updating some data in sql table.

Comment: @peterm: Your posts are highly non-constructive. I'll request you to please do not argue. If you've not understand the `clearly` explained question then please do not reply!

Comment: The "clearly" above is an overestimation. Clearly.

Comment: @user2854563 You can't delete a row (or anything) X times. You can't kill someone twice. Once dead he is dead forever. You can delete X rows though. Is that what you want, to limit the number of rows that the query deletes?

Comment: Can you update your question and add example data for before and after (or a example of the sequence of events you're looking for). The discussion here is because we don't understand what you're trying to do. Alternatively describe the overall functionality so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ypercube: you can if you limit the number of rows the SQL database will look for.

Comment: @ypercube: You're correct. I want to delete X rows having column_value exactly equals to 1

Comment: And also, if I understand correctly, you want to delete X rows that match some condition. Presumably there are more than X rows that match that condition. How do you decide which ones to remove?

Comment: @SpaceDog: MySQL will search the database top-down and delete the first elements that match. Unless you specify an order (for instance name ascending), the oldest rows will be removed first. As stated in the MySQL documentation, one merely uses this for performance issues: one wants a responsive website who doesn't lag for several hours simply because the database contains millions of entries.

Comment: @Commusoft. No, that is incorrect. There is no top-down in SQL tables and the oldest will not always be deleted. The first X rows found that match the condition will be deleted but which ones will be found first depends on how the engine/optimizer will decide to search, on whether there are indexes available (and which) and many other factors. So Spacedog is correct.

Comment: Well in most cases a database is sorted anyhow, simply by specifying a primary key a database will probably sort its records to perform fast primary key matching like in this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/258203/1/0

Comment: @ypercubde @CommuSoft -- I've never seen `limit` used on delete before. Maybe mySQL handles it in a deterministic way, but I'm doubting it -- I strongly suspect that it'll be randomly chosen (based on previous access/database engine quirks) rows that are removed. I'm also struggling to see a use case, maybe if you have X+1 identical rows and you're trying to clear up that database. Relying on 'in most cases' is a recipe for a really obscure bug sometime in the future, unless you can be sure the functionality is reliable.

Comment: The MySQL documentation specifies one: say you run a website and you want to remove all the rows. This might take a while in a db with billions of entries. Then one can query the db with `limit`s, so you can keep the website interactive (and for instance show a message like `"3'000 entries deleted..."`, `"6'000 entries deleted"`). Secondly you can specify `ORDER BY` in the second query as well. For instance delete the first entries alphabetically.

Comment: @Spacedog if an `ORDER BY` is provided, it is deterministic. As for use cases, I can think of deleting a large number of rows in smaller batches (avoiding one huge DELETE statement.)

Comment: @CommuSoft, fair enough. That's a reasonable use case (although it does make the assumption that you're eventually deleting all the rows, so the order of deletion is unimportant).

Comment: @SpaceDog: indeed, my bad... Sorry :(. However as ypercube noted (and I modified my comment at the same moment), one can also use the `ORDER BY` aspect.

Comment: @CommuSoft Cool, no problem. I learnt something new today. :) So that's mySQL specific rather than a general SQL feature?

Comment: @CommuSoft Here's a **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1358a/1)** where the "oldest" rows are not deleted.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't seem to provide a `LIMIT` statement: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html. But one can state there is not really an SQL standard. There are SQL databases who even disagree with basic SQL queries as far as I know.

Comment: @ypercube: Not that I want to start a fight :P, but you state `index (type, details)`. That means that you tell the database you will execute a lot of `WHERE type=... AND details=...` queries (why would you otherwise add it to an index?), so the database will probably sort its data accordingly.

Comment: There is also the (primary) index on `(id)`. But which of the available indexes is used in any query/statement, the optimizer decides. It may decide something else the next time we run it, that is my point.

Comment: Well you made your point :D. Nice example... However I think most databases will execute such query deterministically, but I admit that the exact order is difficult to determine, one should be a Database implementor to know how such queries are resolved.

Comment: @CommuSoft, fair enough. I use PostgreSQL most of the time, but this might come in useful in the future. The reaction of different databases to 'standard SQL' is probably a whole different question. :) Thanks for responses and sticking around to discuss the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the `LIMIT` keyword (according to the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column_value = 1 AND user_id = 2 LIMIT X;
```

Where you replace `X` with a number.

EDIT: (regarding the comment)

I copied this from the specifications, looks like it solves the problem you are trying to tackle:

> The MySQL-specific LIMIT row_count option to DELETE tells the server
>   the maximum number of rows to be deleted before control is returned to
>   the client. This can be used to ensure that a given DELETE statement
>   does not take too much time. You can simply repeat the DELETE
>   statement until the number of affected rows is less than the LIMIT
>   value.

`LIMIT` is a MySQL specific instruction, you cannot use it as a generic SQL query, other databases like PostgreSQL might fail to execute such query.

Another remark: you specified `id` in the query. If you remove rows, you should not specify columns.

I've tested it using SQL Fiddle and it succeeded: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13ccb7/1/0 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/258203/1/0.

Comment: According to the MySQL documentation, it has: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html But not SQL in general. I agree with that.

Comment: When using Single-Table mode, it can be done, but not when you mix up two or more tables or use a view.

Comment: Updated. I wonder if the original query was working since you specified `id` after `DELETE`. In a `DELETE` statement, one does not specify columns.

Comment: OK, can it delete the rows 3 times (like I asked in the question)? I'm asking this because you've one row in the fiddle and the quesry is deleting only that row.

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/258203/1/0 The first three email adresses are deleted... Furthermore I don't see why this aswer is rated -1 while it is, as far as I know, correct. As said in the post, this is not a valid generic SQL query, MySQL however implemented some additional features.

Comment: When I run this query:

`DELETE id FROM table_name WHERE column_value = 1 AND uid = 1 LIMIT 3`

It shows this error: `Unknown table 'id' in MULTI DELETE`

Comment: As I explained already in my post, you should not specify `id`. If you delete a row, you delete it entirely. The correct query is `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column_value = 1 AND uid = 1 LIMIT 3`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the headsup CommuSoft. Your reply is very much appreciated. I'm accepting your answer as best one!